# Length of a matrix without traversing it java

Tags: java, matrix

How can I measure the length of the columns, without traversing the matrix?
I have tried with matrix[].length but it does not work.
The problem I have is that I start with the columns first to go through the matrix, so what I want is to calculate the length of the matrix first and then go through it row by row

Comment: you have to use a loop `for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) int collength = matrix[i].length;`

Comment: what `matrix`? Define "does not work"

Comment: @YCF_L the problem I have is that I start with the columns first to go through the matrix, so what I want is to calculate the length of the matrix first and then go through it row by row

Comment: i already mention that in my solution `matrix.length;`

Comment: @YCF_L For non-square matrices? I want the ones in the columns. For example 8 row x15 col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's easy. every matrix has at least 1 row so you can target that row to find the whole matrix columns number like `matrix[0].length`

Answer (score 0):

For example, your array or arrays(or which you call it matrix) is defined like this :

```
int[][] matrix = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8, 9}
};
```

To get the length of the principal array(matrix) and the length of each array inside (columns) you can use :

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    //-------------------^^^ This will return the numbers of array inside the matrix (3)
    int lengthCol = matrix[i].length;
    //----------------------^^^ This will return the return the length of each array 
    System.out.println(lengthCol);// this will print (3, then 2, then 4)
}
```